# Agrupar json com PHP?

Tags: php, json, array

Como faço para agrupar um json de acordo com um campo?

Tenho o seguinte json:

```
{
  "origem": [
    {
      "id": 154826,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "SAO",
      "sq": 925
    },
    {
      "id": 2289,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "RIO",
      "sq": 925
    },
    {
      "id": 154826,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "SAO",
      "sq": 925
    }
  ]
}
```

Queria agrupa-ló de acordo com o id para que fique assim:

```
{
  "origem": [
    {
      "id": 154826,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "SAO",
      "sq": 925
    },
    {
      "id": 2289,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "RIO",
      "sq": 925
    }
  ]
}
```

No caso seria mais remover os itens repetidos. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Mas e os `"sg": "SAO",` e `"sg": "RIO",`? Vão se perder?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não porque todos que repetem id são iguais. Então só preciso de um e eliminar o resto

Comment: era só pra saber, porque eu estava pensando em sugerir algo diferente mas que iria agrupar de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, deve pegar essa informação e transformar em um `array`, depois fazer um laço de repetição para agregrar essas informações, que no caso eu coloquei o `id` como chave, e depois retornar aquele `JSON` que deseja, exemplo:

```
<?php    
$json = '{
  "origem": [
    {
      "id": 154826,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "SAO",
      "sq": 925
    },
    {
      "id": 2289,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "RIO",
      "sq": 925
    },
    {
      "id": 154826,
      "nm": "",
      "tp": "",
      "am": "",
      "sg": "SAO",
      "sq": 925
    }
  ]
}';    
$rs = (json_decode($json, true)); // transformando os dados em um array
$r0 = array(); // array novo
foreach($rs['origem'] as $r)
{
    $r0[$r["id"]] = $r; // agregando as chaves iguais       
}    
echo json_encode(array_values($r0), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // retornando ao json
```

<sub>[Exemplo IDEONE](https://ideone.com/XLN5K4)</sub>